# ¿Cómo hacer un case anidado?

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: Imagen de referencia]

Tengo una tabla donde según el dato, a veces, la palabra *pallet* aparece en el campo de *PACKUOM3*. Cuando esto sucede, se coloca un valor al lado, el cual requiero para dividir con otro valor.

En otro dato puede que la palabra *PALLET* aparezca debajo del campo *PACKUOM4*, si esto sucede, el valor numérico me aparece debajo de la palabra *PALLET*, el cual necesito para dividir con otro valor.

**¿Cómo puedo crear un case anidado que me permita dividir cuando la palabra pallet aparezca en un campo u otro?**

Actualmente tengo el siguiente código, donde tengo dos condiciones, pero no sé cuál es el criterio para realizar lo que deseo.

```
CASE
    WHEN p.PALLET = 0 THEN 0
    WHEN CAST(QTYRECEIVED AS NUMERIC)/p.PALLET < 1 THEN 1
    ELSE CAST(QTYRECEIVED AS NUMERIC)/p.PALLET
END
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No entiendo porque queres un case... no queres eso, queres un coalesce que compruebe si un campo tiene valor o no, y lo use o use el otro... si pones un ejemplo claro de datos de entrada y como tiene que quedar la salida, te vamos a poder ayudar...

Comment: Si bien haz hecho un esfuerzo ppr tratar de formular bien tu pregunta; en cuestiones de consulta de datos es muy util para poder contestarla los siguientes: 1) La declaracion de las tablas que vas a usar en la consulta; 2) Script de insert para poblar las tablas con los datos de prueba de tu escenario 3) La consulta que has intentado y el reultado que te da (o el mensaje de error) 4) El resultado que esperas obtener de la consulta como solución a tu pregunta (filas y columnas)